# How to choose from two SSAS measure selections in a drop down list in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssas

I want to be able to pass two measure selections from a SSAS cube as a parameter in SSRS and choose to show one of the two in the report.I tried to follow to following tutorial but it didn't work out for me.

https://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/measure-selection-in-ssrs-and-ssas/

Thanks in advance,
Olga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Create a dataset with the parameter label and value that you want to display in your parameters (if you want label and value to be the same then you just need the value).

Step 2. Create a new parameter.

Step 3. Go to parameter properties. Where it says available values, click get values from a query. Point it to your dataset. Specify the label and the value.

That's it.

Bonus: If you want all of your values in the multi-select to be selected by default, specify the table and value in the default values tab.

Comment: Why use a dataset for the parameters? If there is a fixed number just specify them in the parameter list,else it's unnecessary overhead

Comment: As far as I can understand the question, she is trying to have parameters based on measures from her cube.

Comment: You simply specify 2 parameters as values e.g. Measures.MeasureA and Measures.MeasureB with appropriate labels.

Comment: My interpretation is that she wanted dynamic values from the cubes. Apparently she's not going to follow up on this question so we'll never know who's right.

Comment: yes that's right, I'm trying to have parameters based on measures from the cube

Comment: Olga, did you try my solution? Were you able to get it working?

Comment: I did try, but didn't succeed